# BotFramework Post Request Body not being saved in session.userData

Tags: node.js, azure, request, botframework

Using a POST request, I send user submitted info to an API which would give user-specific info.

Now, I want to save the info regurgitated by the POST request as variable that I can use in other functions/dialogues.

I've tried the following:

1. Save the POST request body in a session.userData.xxx variable
2. Declared a global variable and used it to store the body.
3. Declared a variable within the post request wherein I stored the body

A version of the code I did is as follows:

```
    var body2;

    bot.dialog('FunctionA', [
        function (session) {
            session.sendTyping();
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please key-in your App ID:");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.userData.AppID= results.response;
         var options = {
      url: 'APIXYZ.COM',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'               
            },
         body: JSON.stringify({"appID": session.userData.AppID})

        };

        request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body); //logs okay
            session.userData.infoA = body;
        console.log(session.userData.infoA) //logs okay
        body2 = body;
            console.log (body2) // logs ok
        var bodyvar = body;
            console.log (bodyvar) //logs ok

          } else {
              console.log("Error: " + error);
              console.log("Status Code: " + response.statusCode);
          }
        });

        var msg = new builder.Message(session)

        .text("The body is:" + session.userData.infoA) //outputs "The body is undefined", if body2,bodyvar -> empty
        .suggestedActions(
            builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [

                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Ok", "Ok")
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "No", "No")

                ]
            ));
    session.send(msg).endDialog();

    }]).triggerAction({ matches: /^ABC/i });
```

It appears like it only works within the request block, and I cannot use it outside of that. It is logged as undefined when used outside it. I would like to be able to store the POST request body as variable so that I could use them outside this dialogue and also save it in a database.

Thanks!

Edit:

I have declared body2 as a variable outside the dialog and the request block, and have used the variable within the same dialog, just after the request.post

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)

.text("The body contains: " + body2 + " .") 
        .suggestedActions(
            builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [

                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Ok", "Ok")
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "No", "No")

                ]
            ));
```

This outputs `The body contains: undefined .`

I've also tried to use it in another dialog:

```
bot.dialog('Validation', function (session) {
    console.log(body2);
   session.send("The content is : " + body2 +" xx");
    if (body2== "ABC")
    {
        session.sendTyping();
        var msg = new builder.Message(session);
[.......]
```

This results in a `"Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over"` prompt

Comment: You're trying to access `body2` outside of the request body? So long as it's defined outside of it, it should work just fine. I just tested something very similar and it worked. Can you post all of your code and specify where it is you'd like to access `body2` (or the appropriate variable) again?

Comment: ...by "defined", I meant "instantiated".

Comment: @mdrichardson I've updated the question to  accommodate my edits and additional code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `post` request doesn't complete before you execute other functions. In other words, here's what your code is doing:

1. Creates `post` request
2. Executes code with `body2` still undefined
3. `post` request completes and *then* defines `body2` as `body`

You can fix this in two ways:

#### Use async/await

This basically forces all of your code to wait for `request.post` to return data before continuing. If you're not familiar, `async/await` is the newer way to use `Promises` or `.then()`. It is SUPER useful, especially when making HTTP requests. You can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Add `async`

```
async function (session, results) {
    session.userData.AppID= results.response;
    var options = {
        url: 'APIXYZ.COM',
...
```

Add `await`

```
await request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); //logs okay
    session.userData.infoA = body;
```

#### Encapsulate Code Within Your Request Function

Since `request.post` will execute code once it has `error`, `response`, and `body`, you can include any code that needs to use the data that gets returned like this:

```
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); //logs okay
        body2 = body;
        console.log (body2) // logs ok
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("The body is:" + body2)
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [

                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Ok", "Ok"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "No", "No")

                    ]
                ));
        session.send(msg).endDialog();
    } else {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        console.log("Status Code: " + response.statusCode);
    }
});
```

I recommend going the `async/await` route for two reasons:

1. It is super useful in many, many JavaScript scenarios and very good to know
2. If you use `body2` within other dialogs, you'll need to use it anyway. With the "encapsulation" method above, you might still be waiting on a response while another dialog starts that needs `body2`

All that being said, it looks like you're using V3 of the Bot Framework. If this is a new bot, I recommend building it in [V4](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples)--it has newer features and we support it better.